# Operator norm of operator $C[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

$A: \; X \to Y, \; X=C[0,1], \; Y=L_2[0,1], \; Ax(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{1} (t+s)x(\sqrt{s})ds$ 
I proved that the operator is bounded:
$Ax(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}(t+s)x(\sqrt{s})ds \Rightarrow |Ax(t)|^2=|\int\limits_{0}^{1}(t+s)x(\sqrt{s})ds|^2 \leq \\  \leq (\int\limits_{0}^{1} |t+s|^2ds)
\cdot (\int\limits_{0}^{1} |x(\sqrt{s})|^2)ds = \dfrac{3t^2+t+1}{3} (\int\limits_{0}^{1} |x(\sqrt{s})|^2)ds \leq \\\dfrac{3t^2+3t+1}{3} \max\limits_{s \in [0,1]} (x(\sqrt{s}))^2 \Rightarrow \int\limits_{0}^{1} |Ax(t)|^2dt \leq \int\limits_{0}^{1} \dfrac{3t^2+3t+1}{3}\max\limits_{s \in [0,1]} (x(\sqrt{s}))^2dt= \\ = \dfrac{7}{6} \max\limits_{s \in [0,1]} (x(\sqrt{s}))^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{\int\limits_{0}^{1} |Ax(t)|^2dt} \leq \sqrt{\dfrac{7}{6} \max\limits_{s \in [0,1]} (x(\sqrt{s}))^2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{7}{6}}\max\limits_{s \in [0,1]} (x(\sqrt{s})) \Rightarrow (\|Ax\|_{L_2[0,1}) \leq \sqrt{\dfrac{7}{6}} \|x\|_{C[0,1]}$ \

I can't find such a function  $x_0(t)$ to achieve equality. I tried $x_0 \equiv 1$ but then $\|Ax\|=\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{12}}$.

Comment: Did you try $x(t) = t + c$ ?

Comment: If $x(t)=t$ then $\|Ax\|=\sqrt{388/675}$, if $x(t)=1-t$ also bad, $x(t)=t^2$ same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use the Cauchy$-$Schwartz inequality here, it is sufficient to notice that since
$$
|Ax(t)| = \Big|\int_0^1 (t+s) \,x(\sqrt s)\,\mathrm d s\Big| \leq \|x\|_{C^0}\int_0^1(t+s)\,\mathrm d s = t+1/2
$$
it follows that
$$
\int_0^1 |Ax|^2 \leq \int_0^1 (t+1/2)^2\,\mathrm d t = \tfrac{1}{3}\left((3/2)^3 - (1/2)^3\right) = \frac{13}{12}
$$
which is indeed the value you found with $x(t) = 1$.